# How Do I Make my 2D Pong Racquets Move Up and Down, Rather than Side to Side?

Tags: java

I saw a lot of results on how do move a sprite in Java, but I can't find any that suite my code. I'm following a tutorial on how to make a Pong style game.
You can find the tutorial [here](http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game6.html). (That's the part I encountered the problem).

Here's my code for the Racquet class:

```
package com.tennis;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racquet {
private static final int Y = 330;
private static final int WIDTH = 60;
private static final int HEIGHT = 10;
int x = 0;
int xa = 0;
private Game game;

public Racquet(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public void move() {
    if(x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getHeight()-60)
        x = x + xa;
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, 50, 10, 70);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        xa = -1;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        xa = 1;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public int getTopY() {
    return Y;
}
}
```

Now the part I'm looking at that I need help changing is this:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        xa = -1;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        xa = 1;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
```

Alrighty, so the actual problem I have is that I need the Racquet to move up and down along the Y axis, at the current moment it's moving along the X axis.

Answer (score 0):

In your move() function replace x = x + xa to:

```
y = y + xa;
```

Answer (score 0):

x variable supposed to be y, and pass to the 2nd param for fillRect

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(50, x, 10, 70);
}

public abstract void fillRect(int x,
            int y,
            int width,
            int height)
```

x - the x coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.

y - the y coordinate of the rectangle to be filled.

width - the width of the rectangle to be filled.

height - the height of the rectangle to be filled.

Comment: Its not working, I feel like I have an easy to fix error

Answer (score 0):

I was overcomplicating things by trying to make the ping pong racquet move on the Y axis instead of the X axis, so I switched it. Problem solved-ish. Now I can finish the game and continue onto making funner Java games.

So I messed around with these integers,

```
    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, 250, 70, 10);
}
```

Then I made the keys as so:

```
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        xa = -1;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = 1;
}
```